# Can I create a Crypto with a plain certificate?

Tags: java, apache, cryptography, ws-security

For our application we use the class `Crypto` (in the package `org.apache.ws.security.crypto`) for the encryption/decryption and for signature creation/verification.

Currently we create the `Crypto` objects with two key stores (one key store for the client and one for the server), by setting the properties:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider", "org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", password);
properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file", keystoreFile);
properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type", "PKCS12");
```

and creating the `Crypto` instance with it:

```
Crypto crypto = null;
try {
    crypto = CryptoFactory.getInstance(properties); 
}
```

The key store of the server only has a plain certificate (.crt or .cer) and has to be created with it. I don't want to go this way around. Is there a way to create the `Crypto` instance straight away with the certificate instead of creating the key store first?

I tried it by setting the properties like this:

```
properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider", "org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin"); 
properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.x509crl.file", certificateFilePath);   // location
```

but this didn't work for me ("RuntimeException: Cannot instantiate crypto!").

Comment: Can you please indicate what you have against instantiating a key store? It's not like it is a resource intensive operation. Furthermore, a CLR is not a certificate, so setting the `X509crl.file` property and pointing to a certificate will - and should - fail.

Comment: Unrelated to the question: I see you've asked 35 questions already. By now you should have figured out how to format your source code. Please make sure your question is indented correctly, don't leave it up to the community to clean up after yourself.

Comment: The customers have a certificate, if I load the certificate and put it in a keystore, I need to save this keystore temporary somewhere as the property `org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file` (which points to the path of the keystore) needs to be set. This is an extra step I want to avoid. It makes sense that setting `x509crl.file` doesnt work, but are there other properties that you can set to load a certificate?